# In a vanilla Ubuntu LAMP + virtualmin server, how do i allow cache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, cache

I recently set up an Ubuntu 12.04 server with the default LAMP task. Also added virtualmin.

All requests to apache return this in the headers.

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

How/where do i set cache-control to something more sensible to allow browsers to cache content?

Tried putting this in the .htaccess to no avail. mod_expires is enabled. The result is ***double*** Cache-Control headers!

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header add "Cache-Control" "max-age=3600"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 3600 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was related to me starting a php session.

Setting `session_cache_limiter('public')` solved it. You can add it in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter) or in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your site generating these headers. 
Check it's code.

Comment: Just searched the entire site in Coda for the word "cache", it's not there and i wrote it all myself using no external libraries. Any other clues please?

Comment: Grep for word "Header" or "header"

Comment: Just header('Location...

Comment: Ok. You have to grep all site code (including .htaccess'es) and apache configs.